# Custom Magnific Popup Arrows

Tags: position, custom-controls, magnific-popup

So this is going to be kinda silly, but I don't like the arrows for Magnific Popup, and I want to use some png arrows that I created, even moreso I don't want them the default way where they are miles apart, and I don't want them to obstruct content (cause I am using Magnific Popup to gallery some ajax). I really want them bound in div/big square buttons on the side of the image (the height of the image as well) like the first example here:

[image]

and those big black bars on a tv

[image]

I have no idea where the code is to change this, or how to edit the basic construction of the lightbox but I really want to change the arrows (and the x) if someone could direct me to the code where I can do this I will be glad to do it but I feel like I am working blind.

Alternatively, if anyone knows any other lightboxes that allow you to position and design your own arrows and close button, and have a gallery of ajax based items (that is responsive and scrolls) I will gladly switch (I basically want to be behance ha ha)

(also is there anyway we can generate a swipe effect to go through a gallery?)

Feel free to tell me to go to hell if it is impossible :D 
Thanks.